# Using combinatorics to calculate at least one with 0

Tags: combinatorics

Problem is like this:

Telephone number consists of $8$ digits. The first digit is not permitted to be $0$ or $1$.

Question: how many of the telephone numbers contain at least one zero?

I thought if we have $8$ places and 10 possible digits for each except first one that has $8$ possible digits, I would go this way:

$$8 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9$$

The first digit that can't be $0$ or $1$ next that can be zero and the others permitted to take zeros? Am I right?

Comment: Thanks @k170 for editing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many of the telephone numbers don't contain a zero?

There are $8$ possibilities for the firs digit and $9$ for every other. Thus $8\cdot9^7$

How many telephone numbers in total? $8\cdot10^7$

Thus the answer is $8\cdot10^7-8\cdot9^7=41,736,248$

Comment: No no. Question is: how many of the telephone numbers contain at least one zero? at least one zero.

Comment: yeah, if you count how many don't and substract that from the total, you get what you want.

Comment: @ideaot that is exactly what Jorge has answered. Read my answer and then look at what Jorge has done.

Answer (score 1):

Your count will include the phone numbers that DO NOT contain any zero because you have no control over the digits. So the better way is to count for the opposite case I.e. Go for numbers NOT having any zero digit, then subtract this from total number of possible phone numbers.